# Snake Food Sprite

Tags: pygame

This is how food is drawn in my snake game. How would I apply the
"food" sprite to the food. The image is loaded on my computer and I
have gotten it to show up before but is never attached to the actual
food.

```
food = pygame.image.load('meat.png')


for (fx, fy) in self.food:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, FOOD_COLOR, (blockWidth * (fx-1), blockHeight * (fy-1), blockWidth, blockHeight))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not drawing the `food` bitmap to the screen.  Assuming there is a PyGame display named `screen`:

```
food_image = pygame.image.load('meat.png')

for (fx, fy) in self.food:
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, FOOD_COLOR, (blockWidth * (fx-1), blockHeight * (fy-1), blockWidth, blockHeight))
    screen.blit( food_image, ( fx, fy ) )
```